# Looping through XML to create an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, arrays, hashmap

I have the following XML

```
<CallResult>
  <Success>true</Success>
  <Result>
    <ZoneInfo>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Name>test-room</Name>
      <NId>sdfsdg</NId>
    </ZoneInfo>
    <ZoneInfo>
      <Id>16</Id>
      <Name>Dynamic</Name>
      <NId>sadadrwed543th</NId>
    </ZoneInfo>
    <ZoneInfo>
      <Id>32</Id>
      <Name>lobby</Name>
      <NId>ssdfrgfdfg</NId>
    </ZoneInfo>
    <ZoneInfo>
      <Id>33</Id>
      <Name>conf</Name>
      <NId>sdfsfewr232f</NId>
    </ZoneInfo>
  </Result>
  <Message>Success</Message>
</CallResult>
```

I am trying to parse the XML so that each different 'ZoneInfo' attributes is a hash in an array.

E.g.

Zones[0] = Hash[Id => 32, Name => lobby, NId => ssdfrgfdfg]

Zones[1] = Hash[Id => 33, Name => conf, NId => sdfsfewr232f]
etc...

My limited XML parsing knowledge has come a croper. All I really know is how to extract a single element. E.g.

```
doc = REXML::Document.new(xmlData)
doc.elements.each("CallResult/Success") do |ele|
  p ele.text;
end
```

Could someone help with some more info on how to loop through just extracting info from each 'ZoneInfo' element?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use another gem 'nokogiri', maybe the best gem to parse HTML/XML now.

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = "<CallResult> ......"
doc = Nokogiri.XML(str)
Zones = []
doc.xpath('//ZoneInfo').each do |zone|
  Zones << { "Id" => zone.xpath('Id').text, "Name" => zone.xpath('Name').text, "NId" => zone.xpath("NId").text}
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use nori gem

```
require 'nori'
your_hash = Nori.parse(your_xml)
```

And then it should be straightforward to convert this nested hash to an array of hashes if you need to store your data that way.

If you need more info, api doc is here - http://rubydoc.info/gems/nori/1.1.3/frames